# How do I display the git branch in the emacs modeline?

Tags: macos, git, emacs, modeline

By default the modeline like：
[image]

Emacs displays `Git-master` when I am working in a directory that is under the Git version control system.Now I customize modeline in the file `init-modeline.el` like this:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
    (list
        ;; the buffer name; the file name as a tool tip
        '(:eval (propertize "%b " 'face font-lock-keyword-face
        'help-echo (buffer-file-name)))

        ;; line and column
        "("
        "%02l" "," "%01c"
        ") "
        ......
))
```

Then add `(require 'init-modeline)` to `init.el`.

Now emacs does not display git branch in the emacs modeline, so I add `'(vc-mode vc-mode)` to `init-modeline.el` like this:

```
    (setq-default mode-line-format
    (list
        ;; the buffer name; the file name as a tool tip
        '(:eval (propertize "%b " 'face font-lock-keyword-face
        'help-echo (buffer-file-name)))

        ;; line and column
        "("
        "%02l" "," "%01c"
        ") "

        '(vc-mode vc-mode)
        ......
))
```

Now modeline shows like this:

[image]

It only shows `-master`.How can I show `Git-master`?

The value of variable `vc-mode` in `init-mode` buffer like:

```
vc-mode's value is #(" :master" 0 1
  (face sml/vc-edited)
  1 8
  (help-echo "Locally modified file under the Git version control system\nCurrent revision: master\nmouse-1: Version Control menu" face sml/vc-edited local-map
         (keymap
          (mode-line keymap
                     (down-mouse-1 menu-item "Version Control" vc-menu-map :filter vc-menu-map-filter)))
         mouse-face mode-line-highlight))

Local in buffer init.el; global value is nil

  Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set.
  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
```

Comment: Show the value of variable `vc-mode` in your `..init.el` buffer.

Comment: Thanks,seem to not work

Comment: Well that's not useful. artscan was asking you to tell us the what value of the `vc-mode` variable is in your `init.el` buffer. If the value is `-master` then your mode line format is fine. If the value is `Git-master` then you'll want to establish why it gets truncated when displayed.

Comment: Can you please type `C-h v` `vc-mode` `RET` in your `init.el` buffer and tell us what the value is? That's all we're asking for.

Comment: So we can now see that `vc-mode` is just `" :master"`, which explains why `"Git"` doesn't appear (I see a value of `" Git:master"`, by comparison). I'm guessing that the `sml/vc-edited` face is responsible for displaying the `:` as `-` in your mode line. I presume that's some third-party thing, so that same library *might* be responsible for removing the `Git` prefix. I would try disabling it (whatever it is), and see if you get the prefix back again.

Comment: @phils As you say, I disabled third-part mode about mode-line, and I get the prefix.Thank you.